# how to update <p> element as I change the <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, onchange

I have tried lot of ways to update the p element, I tried the regular fuction too, but somehow I am getting issues whith (this) keyword. I have searched so many places but all they have is the solution for onchange event for an input tag not the textarea tag.

[click here to see the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2LiR.jpg)

Comment: can you post the code here instead of image.

Comment: In `this.preview.innerHTML`, `this` refer to `window` object as `arrow` functions do not have there own `this`. Instead use `preview.innerHTML=editor.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use this for the preview and the editor var to get the value

```js
var editor = document.getElementById("editor"); 

var preview = document.getElementById("preview");


editor.addEventListener("change",() => {


this.preview.innerHTML = "";

this.preview.innerHTML =  editor.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="editor" type="text"></textarea>

<p id="preview"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `this.preview.innerHTML`, `this` refer to `window` object as arrow functions do not have there own `this`. As you already have reference of `editor` and `preview`, you can directly use `preview.textContent= editor.value;`

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor");
const preview = document.getElementById("preview");

editor.addEventListener('change', () => {
  preview.textContent= editor.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
 <p id="preview">sdsd</p>
```

using `this`

```js
const preview = document.getElementById("preview");

// Here `this` refer to `textarea` element
editor.addEventListener('change', function() {
  preview.textContent = this.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<p id="preview">sdsd</p>
```

Comment: the <p> element is updated oncew i click outside the textarea. Is there a way to update the <p> element simulatneously as I update the textarea?

Comment: Never mind... I just had to use "keyup" for that. Thank you for the help!